# Tradeoffs with bulk update on high-traffic table

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a SQL Server table that has millions of rows and receives over 2000 inserts per minute.   A separate process needs to do a bulk update on this table, let's say with a where clause that will update 1000 rows.  But it doesn't care about performance and could optionally run 1000 single-row updates using the primary key.

If the bulk update runs too long, it will block the incoming insertions, right?   Whereas updating rows individually will allow insertions to squeak through the cracks and not block?   So from the standpoint of optimizing performance for the insertions, am I better off running the updates one row at a time?

Comment: Inserts wont block updates(unless you request table lock..).if  your update is not blocking entire table(single transaction taking more than 5000 locks),i don't see any issues.i recommend raising the question on DBA SE with sample schema and indexes on table as well along with sample update queries

Answer (score 0):

Updates will not block the insert but you might get an unexpected behavior if the where condition of the where condition is not applied to the new inserted rows.. So it's better to review the logic of the application to make sure that the new inserted rows are not needed in the update.
But in general the bulk update is much better than single updates.